# Regex person name comparision

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex

I'm not very good with Regex and I was looking over the internet for this but couldn't find it. On my DB I'm storing first_name, second_name and last_name but on my website I only have two texboxes (One for first_name and the other for last_name). I want to include a checking to allow include first_name and second_name on the same textbox. So the checking should be:

- Only allow letters, apostrophe and spaces
- If the textbox with first_name doesn't contain an space, max length is 50 characters
- If contain space, max length is 50 first word + space + (50 the rest, as many words as you want)

is this possible using a Regex? Thanks, any idea will be welcome.

**UPDATE**

I found another approach using a JS library https://github.com/joshfraser/JavaScript-Name-Parser. I'll do some modifications:

- Check the lengths of parsed name
- Localize the texts like 'Dr.', 'Mr.'

Then I'll store the name separately on the DB, as this is a short register form I want as less textboxes as possible. Then the user will be able to go to his profile and edit the data separately if it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
/^[A-Z']{1,50}(\s[A-Z'\s]{1,50})?$/i
```

(UPDATE: Note that although I believe the above JS regex matches your stated requirement, I'm not sure that your requirement matches with real-world names because you seem to be assuming that the first space marks the end of the first name. I have some friends with Asian names where their first name has a space in it. I also have a friend who spells her first name "Ann Marie" with a space rather than a hyphen; she also has a middle name, and in her case it would be incorrect to assue that "Marie" is part of the middle name.)

Comment: You still need to make the last group optional. (put a space after the closing parenthesis).

Comment: This is wrong. This requires a space. The last group has to be made optional

Comment: @drewag and Pogo - Thanks, I just missed typing the `?` on the end.

Comment: Haha not to nitpick, but wouldn't the name (never) start with an apostrophe? So technically the first character set shouldn't include an apostrophe, and the `{}` values should change. I know there are other problems with the original question as you pointed out, I'm just saying :)

Comment: @ianpgall - Yes. There are (usually informal) English words that can start or end with an apostrophe, but I don't think I've ever seen a _name_ that did so. I don't know much about other languages though. Easy enough to change the regex, but I probably wouldn't bother validating user-entered names down to that level: if somebody insists that their name starts with an apostrophe I'd let 'em enter it like that.

Comment: Sorry but this seems not working for me. It doesn't match a simple name like 'Dimitry Fernandez'. I found another approach using a library in JS [https://github.com/joshfraser/JavaScript-Name-Parser](https://github.com/joshfraser/JavaScript-Name-Parser). I'll modify it to check the lengths, localize the texts like 'Dr., Mr.'. Then I'll store the name separately on the DB, as this is a short register form I want as less textboxes as possible. Then the user will be able to go to his profile and edit the data if it's wrong.

Comment: _"It doesn't match a simple name like 'Dimitry Fernandez'."_ - Yes it does, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/FfGWe/ (If you modify the name in that demo such that the first name is more than 50 characters or non-alphabet characters you'll notice it doesn't match.)

Answer (score 1):

While I think this is possible to do in regex I think it is easier and cleaner to split the task up a bit before using regex. I recommend you perform a split on the space character and then check the resulting string lengths and then with a regex ensure only letters and apostrophe.